# How can I pause selected objects in a motion scene?

Tags: visual-effects

Hey guys, the question I'm asking can easily be understood by just watching the video via the above link, if anyone knows what this effect is called, I'll much appreciate it, bless up!

Answer (score 1):

It's like a freeze frame effect.  I reckon they've just asked all the actors to hold still, and for the few shots that can't work in real life (the baseball, the spilling coffee etc) they've [tracked the camera movement](https://www.schoolofmotion.com/blog/how-to-use-camera-tracker-after-effects) and added in a 3D version of the objects (eg [this coffee demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B0QM4Cft5c&ab_channel=CGCookie) in Blender).  You can see the actors moving in some of the scenes, eg his eyes move at 2m11, back of the had at 0m36, etc..

Comment: None of the people in that video moved a inch except for the two, watch closely, nothing else moved except for them... Thanks for your help anyway, I appreciate it

Comment: I think maybe the director merged two different clips, froze one and kept the other in motion? The question is how'd that happen...

Comment: https://youtu.be/9-h7ltwACLs here's another video with the same concept, kindly view it

Comment: These aren’t massive productions - I reckon they’re just holding still. To do what you’re suggesting you’d need to use motion control across both scenes. Easier to just tell actors to freeze and use fast edits.

Comment: I hear you, thanks for the ideas

Comment: Yep - this video has very little trickery at all. I'm not convinced the baseball is 3D tracked either - I think it's old school.